# check condition before signup form submission in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a very simple task to be done, on my registration.phtml page, I would liek to check the Affiliated Code entered is correct or not before submitting the form for signup.

To do so, I added a Input button like this:

```
<input type="button" name="checkcode" id="checkcode" class="action primary" value="Check Code">

$('#checkcode').on('click', function() {
        console.log('I am called');
        $.ajax({
            url:"checkcode.php",    //the page containing php script
            type: "post",    //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {referral_code: $('#referral_code').val()},
            success:function(result){
                if (result.flag == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("sub").disabled = true;
                } else { document.getElementById("sub").disabled = false;}
            }
        });
    });
```

checkcode.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Create account form template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register
 */
?>

<?php
// Get Affiliate information
    $_dataHelper = $this->helper('MW\Affiliate\Helper\Data');
    $isEnabled = $_dataHelper->moduleEnabled();
    $refCode = $_POST["referral_code"];
    $isValid = $_dataHelper->checkReferralCode($refCode);
    echo json_encode(array("flag"=>$isValid));
?>
```

In a nutshell, I simple like to check this code $_dataHelper->checkReferralCode($refCode); before submission.

I am non Magento and non php programmer. Just understand the logic here.

Comment: Where you are facing issue ?

Comment: customer/account/create/_nosecret/1/checkcode.php it is showing 404 in console

Comment: That means this file is not getting call - customer/account/create/_nosecret/1/checkcode.php

Comment: Is "checkcode.php" is block ?

Comment: You can call controller from ajax, in controller you can check the condition.

Comment: I really don't know how to, this is just a little task off my tech stack. This function checkReferralCode is written in my Data Helper Class

Comment: I tried to use the same registration.phtml file for the same but there was postback issue. What I simply want is to check Valid Code before form gets submit. It could be either by additional button or check condition before form submission.

Comment: Well, i would advise you to 1 - create controller 2 - inject the helper class in controller 3 -call this controller on submit button & check "isValid" if not valid just return it.